# Segue to present contents of UITableViewController and NavigationController in iPad popover

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitableview, segue

I have a segue that works for iPhone code to present the contents of a tableViewController embedded in a Navigation controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    tvc = (MyTableViewController *)[nc.viewControllers lastObject];
    tvc.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
}
```

tvc is a storyboard item, UITableViewController subclass, embedded in a navigationController. I am trying to find the easiest way to use the same setup on iPad, but present the contents in a popover, with a navigation controller, as opposed to presenting full screen as it's doing now. Else do I need to create a new viewController without using this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom UIStoryboardPopoverSegue, with the following perform code:

```
- (void)perform
{
    UITableViewController *src = (UITableViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    MyController *dst = (MyController *) self.destinationViewController;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dst];


    UITableViewCell *cell = [src.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[src.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];

    UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];

    dst.popoverController = pop;

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(475, src.view.frame.size.height);
    pop.popoverContentSize = size;


    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:cell.frame
                         inView:src.tableView
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                       animated:YES];
}
```

The downside of this is that it requires a seque that is custom to destination view controller.  The upside is an easy to implement and support, well functioning popover segue.